# SSIS Package with Execute Process Task does not work when deployed to remote SSIS Catalog

Tags: process, ssis, catalog

I am using Integration Services 2012. I have a simple Console Application that just prints "Hello World". This Console Application (.exe file) is located on D drive of my workstation.

I have a Visual Studio 2012 project that has a package named **Process.dtsx**. It has an **Execute Process Task** that just executes the exe file, **Hello.exe**, whose duty is just to print "Hello World!" in the screen.

I can execute the **Processe.dtsx** package from Visual Studio without any problem. 
I can execute this package using **dtexec** command without any problem.
I can also deploy the package into SSIS Catalog which is SSIS instance in my **local workstation** without any problem.

But when I deploy the package into SSIS Catalog of **remote machine**, the package fails to execute throwing following error.

*Execute Process Task:Error: File/Process "D:...Hello.exe" is not in path.*

I also did some sort of experiments with deployment over SSIS Catalog in both local and remote machines. Below are my results.

[image]

The deployed package is not able to find the location of exe file. I guess this is a kind of permission issue.

Help Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hello.exe is installed on your local machine and so anything running on your local machine will be able to see and execute it. When you run the package on the server it cannot see the hello.exe on your local machine and so it fails.

In order for it to work the hello.exe must be installed somewhere the server can see it, - either on the server itself or in a common shared network path.